# How to prompt user for password and use that input to change Windows password?

Tags: python, powershell

I have a Python client program that connects to a server program.
In the client program, I want to prompt the user for their Windows username and then ask them for a new password.

I'm going to send the username and password to the server program and run a PowerShell command to change the password.

Is there a way that I can grab the password from the user in the program below and use that input to give the new password to Powershell?

Currently it will not do anything with the password that is given.  The user has to enter their password 2 more times.  I just want to take the original password supplied and use that to give to PowerShell.

```
import subprocess

user = input('Enter Windows Username: ')
password = input('Enter New Password: ')

subprocess.call(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", "Set-ADAccountPassword " + user + " -NewPassword $newpwd –Reset"])
```

**Update**

```
import subprocess

user = input('Enter Windows Username: ')
password = input('Enter New Password: ')

command = subprocess.call(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", "Set-ADAccountPassword " + user + " -NewPassword {0} –Reset"])
formatted_command = command.format(password)

print(formatted_command)
```

And I get the error AttributeError: 'init' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: You need to format your command to include your password variable in the subprocess.call method.

Comment: Is that possible to include the password in the PowerShell command?

Comment: For subprocess.call you just need to pass a list of strings which make up your command.  I would recommend using the str.format() method to build a command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the password into the command string.  Warning, you should sanitize password before generating a command with it because it could cause security issues.

```
command = "This is my cool command with a parameter included: {0}"
password = "super_secret_password"

formatted_command = command.format(password)

print(formatted_command)
```

For formatting the command you can try a couple different methods...

```
command = subprocess.call([
    "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
    "Set-ADAccountPassword {0}".format(user),
    "-NewPassword {0}".format(password),
    "–Reset"
])

# OR

command = subprocess.call([
    "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
    "Set-ADAccountPassword",
    user,
    "-NewPassword",
    password,
    "–Reset"
])
```

Comment: I added what I am now trying above.  I'm getting an AttributeError: 'init' object has no attribute 'format'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
import os

user = input('Enter Windows Username: ')
password = input('Enter New Password: ')

os.system("net user " + user + " " + password)
```

`os.system("net user " + user + " " + password)` means this:
"net user Prox new_password"

By using this command, you change the password of the user directly
using CMD (Windows Command-line)

To run this successfully, run the file as administrator